# Exception thrown in stream callback is not being passed to onError callback

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some bluetooth connection code in my Flutter app.

I have provided an onError callback to the stream.listen() method. The device.connect() call is throwing an exception, but onError is never called, the VSCode extension is treating that exception as an uncaught exception.

How am I supposed to catch the exception in this case?

```
    var stream = FlutterBlue.instance.scan();
    var sub = stream.listen(
      (scanResult) async {
        if (scanResult.device.name == _beacon.id) {
          device = scanResult.device;
          await device.connect();
        }
      },
      onError: (error) {
        print(error); // never prints
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onError` parameter of the `Stream.listen` method catches error which happens *inside* the Stream. Here is a small example:

```dart
void main() {
  final _stream = Stream.fromFuture(
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 1),
      () {
        throw 'Error';
      },
    ),
  );

  _stream.listen(
    (_) {
      print('Got an event');
    },
    onError: (_) {
      print('Caught the error');
    },
  );
}
```

Here the error **is** caught.

However if you want to catch on error inside the first callback you have to use the classic `try-catch`:

```dart
void main() {
  final _stream = Stream.value(0);

  _stream.listen(
    (_) {
      try {
        print('Got an event');
        throw 'Error';
      } catch (_) {
        print('Caught an error inside event listen');
      }
    },
    onError: (_) {
      print('Caught the error');
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thanks